# Why do we call `super.viewDidLoad` in `UIViewController` when it has an empty implementation by default?

Tags: ios, swift

I looked into the code of the `viewDidLoad` function defined in `UIViewController` and this was the only line of code I found:

```swift
open func viewDidLoad()
```

It appears to me that it has an empty implementation. If so, then why do we call `super.viewDidLoad` when we override the function even though it will do nothing?

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Other code to execute
    }
```

Comment: Did you “jump to definition” in Xcode? That shows you only the declaration. The implementation is not shown. UIKit is not open source.

Comment: I see! Thanks for the clarification. So that means we may never know what the `viewDidLoad` actually does. But why does the view load normally without any noticeable problems (at least to my eyes) when I delete `super.viewDidLoad` and run the app?

Comment: It’s *possible* that the default implementation of `viewDidLoad` in `UIViewController` does nothing. Without the source or stepping in the debugger we can’t be sure. And it might change in the future. It’s always good practice to call super in these sort of view lifecycle methods in case there is something the superclass does. If you were to add your own view controller base class and change `ViewController` to inherit from that, then your base class might be doing something important  in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

The code is just part of the template.

Usually there is ***other code to execute*** in `viewDidLoad`, so having the method by default is pretty convenient.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621495-viewdidload?language=objc) it's not even required – but good practice – to call `super` if you **do** implement the method. If you don't need `viewDidLoad` delete it.